# Overload between rvalue reference and const lvalue reference in template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, rvalue-reference

I want to overload two functions based on whether the argument is a temporary object, so I write code like this:

```
#include <iostream>

void f(int &&)
{
  std::cout << "&&" << std::endl;
}

void f(const int&)
{
  std::cout << "const &" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  int i;
  f(i);
  f(i + 1);
}
```

And it corrently output:

```
const &
&&
```

However, when I change the code to use template like this:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void f(T &&)
{
  std::cout << "&&" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void f(const T&)
{
  std::cout << "const &" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  int i;
  f(i);
  f(i + 1);
}
```

The output becomes:

```
&&
&&
```

What's the problem? How can I optimize for moveable temporary object when using template?

edit:

Actually, this is a test code when I read C++ Primer. It says:

```
template <typename T> void f(T&&);       // binds to nonconst rvalues
template <typename T> void f(const T&);  // lvalues and const rvalues
```

After my experiment, it seems the book makes a mistake here.

Comment: what do you mean by *"How can I optimize for moveable temporary object when using template"* ? `T&&` itself is optimal since it binds to everything and allows you to restore the value category of the expression used as the argument

Comment: @PiotrS. For example, if it binds variable i to const T&, and binds expression i + 1 to T&&, then I can move resources from the temporary oject generated by i + 1.

Comment: that's why there is a conditional move, which is `std::forward<T>`, depending on the type deduced for `T` it will either move or not at all. You don't have to explicitly use `std::move` for rvalues. Note that `T&&` where `T` is a type template parameter is a *forwarding reference*, which behaves differently than a regular rvalue reference

Comment: @PiotrS. When I use rvalue reference for function parameter, I expect this parameter always bound to temporary object. But in this case, it also bound to variable.

Comment: `T&&` with `T` being a type template parameter is a *forwarding reference*, not an *rvalue reference*, everything under the sun can be bound by a forwarding reference

Comment: @delphifirst Look up "universal reference" (or, since CppCon 2014, "forwarding reference"). Scott Meyers has material on it (he coined the original term), including an entire talk somewhere on Channel 9.

Comment: @PiotrS. My code is based on an example given by C++ Primer (as I metioned in "edit"). Is this a mistake in the book?

Comment: @delphifirst yes, the book is wrong, you should watch [Universal References in C++11](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Scott-Meyers-Universal-References-in-Cpp11), and [Type Deduction and Why You Care](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/CPP/C-PP-Con-2014/Type-Deduction-and-Why-You-Care)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863603/how-to-make-template-rvalue-reference-parameter-only-bind-to-rvalue-reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template <typename T>
void f(T &&)
{
  std::cout << "&&" << std::endl;
}
```

Uses *<strike>universal</strike> forwarding reference* and allows any types with reference collapsing.

You have to use `T` with a no deducing context as wrapping your code into a struct:

```
template <typename T>
struct helper
{

    void f(T &&)
    {
      std::cout << "&&" << std::endl;
    }

    void f(const T&)
    {
      std::cout << "const &" << std::endl;
    }

};

template <typename T>
void f(T &&t)
{
     helper<typename std::decay<T>::type>().f(std::forward<T>(t));
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/bRErM5)

Comment: std::decay, std::forward,... It seems I have to learn more before I understand this behavior. -_-||